# Loops in Python

Tags: python

Total Python newbie/noob here.

I have to write a code that asks the user to input 3 or more company names. If a) the company has already been entered, a new name should be asked and b) if the company does not exists (I have a dozen of so csv files from company shares), a new one should be asked as well.

It's a task for uni and the instructions said: "The program asks the user to enter at least three shares. However, if the share is already specified, or the file does not exist, a new one must be requested." After a list of companies is created, it must be sent to another module which then reads the corresponding csv files based on this list and reads from them the opening and closing values.

```py
from os import path
import csv

def read_company():
    companies = []

    while True:
        company = input("Enter a company")
        if company in companies:
            print("Company already entered. Enter a new one.")
        else:
            company.append(company)
        if company == False:
            company = "Company"
            if not path.exists(company + '.csv'):
                print(company + ' does not exist. Enter a new one') .format(company=company)
            else: 
                break

    return company
```

1. Fairly certain the break is incorrect as it just stops the program instead of asking for a new one. No idea how to fix it.
2. Should False even be used?

Comment: if company == False will only ever be True if the it is an empty string `''`.  Also it should be `companies.append(company)`.  Your instructions don't really make sense though... when should the program stop asking for names and then what do you do with the names afterward?

Comment: It's a task for uni and the instructions said: "The program asks the user to enter at least three shares. However, if the share is already specified, or the file does not exist, a new one must be requested." After a list of companies is created, it must be sent to another module which then reads the corresponding csv files based on this list and reads from them the opening and closing values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, break needs to be used somewhere or the while True loop will never end.

Your second question, No I don't think False should be used in this context.

Here is what you could do.

```
from os import path

def read_company():
    companies = []

    while len(companies) < 3:
        company = input("Enter a company")
        if company in companies:
            print("Company already entered. Enter a new one.")
        elif not path.exists(company + '.csv'):
            print(company + ' does not exist. Enter a new one') 
        else:
            companies.append(company)
    return companies
```

Instead of using `break` I opted to use a condition in the while loop, so `break` was no longer necessary.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I just cannot seem to master Python. Java never was an issue but Python is giving me straight up nightmares.

Comment: And thank you for the explanation, which I am writing down because I have to defend my script on my exam and I'm sure that question will be asked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `company.append(companies)` as you want to add this company to a list of companies within the list.